# Error Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

I'm developing a windows form application.When I run it it gives me a accessibility issue.please hep me out.

**MainForm** Code is

```
    namespace Tutorial2_WebForms
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        private UserDetails mainUD;

        public UserDetails MainUD
        {
            get { return mainUD; }
            set { mainUD = value; }
        }
```

[image]

**UserDetails** class would be as follows

[image]

and the **error** is 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your User Details class is private because you have not specified an access modifier whereas your MainUD property is public.

User details class should be made public.

```
public class UserDetails
{
   ...
}



public partial class FormMain : Form
{
        private UserDetails mainUD;

        public UserDetails MainUD
        {
            get { return mainUD; }
            set { mainUD = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: but when i change UserDetails object (mainUD) to public , then it also get underlined as MainUD. and gives the same error twice

Comment: Did you change the User details class definition, or the property on your form?

Answer (score 2):

`UserDetails` is internal but you are using it as an `public` property in the `MainForm`. That's because **default access modifier for class types is internal**. Make the `UserDetails` as public and everything will be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserDetails` class does not specify an access modifier, so defaults to `internal` (i.e. it can only be accessed by classes inside the same assembly).

You have a public class (FormMain) which exposes the `UserDetails` class, but clients will not actually have access to that as it is protected. Therefore, your compiler is erroring.

Fix is to change `UserDetails` to public.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the class `UserDetails` `public`.  Classes are `internal` by default:

```
public class UserDetails 
{
    ...
```

Since your form is `public` and exposes the `UserDetails` class through a property that class needs to be `public` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mark UserDetails class as

```
public class UserDetails
{
 ...
}
```

Reason being when anyone would access the property they would see a return type that is otherwise non-existent. By default the class is marked internal.